# PyTables RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, pytables

I'm trying to write a HDF in PyTables and I'm currently getting this runtime exception thrown in one of my threads. Btw, I am locking thread access to writing specific tables within PyTables.

```
Exception in thread ICE_USF_T:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bennett\development\MarketDataReader\IO\__init__.py", line 16, in run
    self.socket.rec()
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bennett\development\MarketDataReader\IO\MarketSocket.py", line 32, in rec
    self.parser.parse(self.sock.recv(10240))
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bennett\development\MarketDataReader\Parser\Parser.py", line 56, in parse
    Interface.writeTradUpdate(TradeUpdate(instrumentId, timestamp, messageType, tradeType, price, quantity))
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bennett\development\MarketDataReader\PyTablesInterface\Interface.py", line 19, in writeTradUpdate
    TradeDataWrapper.updateTrade(update.getInstrumentId(), update.getTimeStamp(), price, quant, update.getYearMonth(), update.getDay())
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bennett\development\MarketDataReader\PyTablesInterface\TradeDataWrapper.py", line 44, in updateTrade
    file.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 2107, in flush
    for path, refnode in self._aliveNodes.iteritems():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```